# Remove a tag in Runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
<h1 id="logo">
    <a class="brand" href="/cgi-bin/koha/opac-main.pl">                           
        CSU Library                            
    </a>
</h1>
```

When my browser width is 701px and above, I don't want this to be seen (edit clarification: the element should be deleted from my html code); otherwise, the  tag can be seen normally when my browser width is below 701px.

Is there any way I can do that? I don't know where to go from this code.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px){
    ....??
}
```

Comment: look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: do u using bootstrap? if yes which one?

Comment: @kefy --> yes I've been using bootstrap 3.

Comment: FYI for Bootstrap 3: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily achieved in CSS if this is a responsive website you are building.

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { 
   #logo {
       display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AlyssaGono Please explain exactly what you want in the question next time.

Comment: @AlyssaGono This does not satisfy your previous comment as it does not delete the html. Is this what you wanted or did you want to delete the html? Why did you delete your comment?

Answer (score 1):

For [Modern browsers and IE9 and above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#Browser_compatibility) you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) like

```
#logo {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 701px) {
  #logo {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as css

```
#logo { display : none; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px){
#logo { display : block; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One method is to use media queries and another way is with jquery as :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 701)
    {
       $("#logo").hide()
    }
    else
    {
       $("#logo").show()
    }
});
```

OR

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 701)
        $("#logo").hide()
    else
        $("#logo").show()
 });
```

Comment: Though I didn't downvote (yet) I see at least two problems: 1. What about smaller screens w/o any resize action? 2. You didn't restore on the opposite action.

Answer (score -1):

According to the asker's comment... "but it leaves a blank space, and that's not what I want. I wanted it to be totally deleted from my html."

Yes, it is possible, but you'll need to use javascript. It is very simple with jQuery:

```
$("#logo").remove();
```